# When offsetdescendantrecttomycoords is used?

Tags: android, android-view

I was following an online tutorial, and he used off offsetdescendantrecttomycoords. I researched a lot, but was unable to find any satisfactory  explanation. I referred to the docs and it says 
 "Offset a rectangle that is in a descendant's coordinate space into our coordinate space"
 I dont get it.. what is our coordinate space ??

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we have a layout hierarchy like this:

> grandParent/parent/child

and each level of hierarchy has 10dp layout padding.
if you need to calculate the space between child top edge and grandParent top edge. then you can do it like this:

```
 private int getTopWithinGrandParent(View child) {
    child.getDrawingRect(mTempRect);
    mGrandParent.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(child, mTempRect);
    return mTempRect.top;
}
```

offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords method is used, when you have more than 2 nested views (3 or more) and you want to calculate offset of descendant views relative to grand parent or other higher level ancestors (but for direct parent, calling this method is not necessary).